# ssmtp fails to install

Tags: software-installation, apt

I tried to install ssmtp but it fails. I updated and upgraded everything before trying this command but it displays this error message.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc $ sudo apt-get install ssmtp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ssmtp
```

Can this be fixed? If not, other alternatives to ssmtp? I am trying to run a python program and email the results to me. Alternatives are welcome.

Comment: http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/ssmtp/

Comment: Are you able to install other packages normally, @Winston? Could you also [edit] to include `/etc/apt/sources.list` (particularly if you aren't able to find other packages - as this would indicate you're not able to fetch from the repos correctly). And which version of Raspbian is this?

Comment: I am on a pre-installed version of raspian - Linux raspberrypi 4.9.80-v7+ #1098 SMP Fri Mar 9 19:11:42 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: I have installed many packages using this method. I have been doing various projects off of the Raspberry Pi site and that involves adding packages to complete the projects.

Comment: Did you get chance to check your `/etc/apt/sources.list`? It would seem likely that you aren't using the same repo that Fabian linked to (or `apt-get update` didn't work right)

Comment: I did check that now and only one line is in there-deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that there is no packet `ssmtp` in the repository of `raspbian 2018-03-13`. You may consider to download it from the link *@Fabian* has given in his comment and then install it manually with:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo dpkg --install ssmtp_2.64-8_armhf.deb
```

But before doing it read http://packages.qa.debian.org/s/ssmtp.html. Seems there is a reason it isn't in the repository because it's a little bit out dated with errors and warnings reported.

Comment: I saw it was placed in unstable on the Debian package site. I guess now I will look for an alternative.

Comment: Ingo do you mean the repository on raspberrypi.org or raspbian.org (regarding the difference: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82118/difference-between-raspbian-repositories )?

Comment: @Fabian I mean from the `Raspbian 2018-03-13` image the default entries in _/etc/apt/sources.list_: `deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi` and in _/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list_: `deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui`

Comment: @WinstonBrown "will look for an alternative" try `exim4`